# Wrapping the code into a method in a different class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

--main file

```
    def test_e2e(self):
    # Home Page
    # Object created for HomePage class in home_page file
    home_page = HomePage(self.driver)

    # CheckOut Page
    # Object created for CheckOutPage class in home_page file
    checkout_page = home_page.shop_items()

    # get product names
    products = checkout_page.get_products()

    for product in products:
        product_name = product.find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text
```

-- checkoutpagefile

```
class CheckOutPage:
products = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='card h-100']")
product_text = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div h4")

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

#  products = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='card h-100']")
# find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text

def get_products(self):
    # get the products
    return self.driver.find_elements(*CheckOutPage.products)

def getproduct_text(self):
    # get product text
    pass
```

I would like to just remove this "".find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text"" part in main file  and wrap into checkoutpage class in a method, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best implementation, but I'd go about adding below methods to CheckOutPage class.

```
# Product as an argument
def get_product_text(self, product):
    return product.find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text

# Products as an argument
def get_products_text(self, products):
    return [product.find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text for product in products]
```

or

```
# If the sole purpose of get_products method is to only get the products text
def get_products_text(self):
    products = self.get_products()
    return [product.find_element_by_css_selector("div h4").text for product in products]
```